# C++ Segmentation Fault with vectors and strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault on one part of my code and I have looked through and fixed most of the errors I've seen, but I can't find all the segmentation faults.

This piece of the code is just checking if there are single quotes in tokens of the vector and combining single quoted strings into one token.

```
void file_parser::check_quote(vector<string> tokens)
{
    bool has_quote = false;
    string tmpstr;
    unsigned int FirstQuote = 0;
    unsigned int SecondQuote;
    string tmp;
    string tmpstr2;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= tokens.size() - 1; i++) {
        tmp = tokens[i].c_str();
        for (unsigned int m = 0; m <= tmp.size() - 1; m++) {
            if (tmp[m] == '\'') {
                has_quote = true;
                FirstQuote = m;
            }
            if (has_quote && m != FirstQuote && tmp[m] == '\'') {
                SecondQuote = m;
                for (unsigned int k = FirstQuote; k <= SecondQuote; k++) {
                    tmpstr += tokens[k];
                }
                tokens.insert(tokens.begin() + FirstQuote, tmpstr);
                for (unsigned int j = FirstQuote + 1; j <= tokens.size() - 1; j++) {
                    for (unsigned int l = SecondQuote + 1; l <= tokens.size() - 1; l++) {
                        tmpstr2 = tokens[SecondQuote + 1];
                        tokens.insert(tokens.begin() + j, tmpstr2);
                    }
                }
                int test = tokens.size() - SecondQuote + 1;
                while (test > 0) {
                    tokens.erase(tokens.end() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the seg fault happening on?

Comment: The general issue I see is that you're changing the vector while you're looping over the vector.  That type of behavior in a loop is practically begging for a seg-fault to happen.

Comment: Doing this: `tokens.insert(tokens.begin() + j, tmpstr2);` inside a loop limited by this: `l <= tokens.size() - 1` ... exactly when do you expect to ever actually hit that limit and break the loop ? Your current problem is with your code, but the *actual* problem you're trying to solve a little more elusive. What are you trying to do? Why do you think this will do it? This is just a quote-matching algorithm? Is that the real plan?

Comment: @user3339703 - If you can explain your requirements a little more in detail, maybe someone can suggest a much better way of adjusting your vector.  Right now, my eyes are bleeding at looking at your code.  Maybe a couple or so STL algorithms would do the job instead of the (hard-to-maintain and debug) loops.

Comment: Or maybe you should use a parser generator: `flex` and `bison`.

Comment: Yeah you're right I didn't notice that I was increasing the size by each pass on a loop depended by size

Comment: But even so, please rethink how you've coded this.  In this day and age of C++, especially the STL and algorithms, loops coded like this should be a rare event.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This part of the code is reading the line in the vector token. Checking if the the token has single quote in it, if so flagging and searching for the second single quote. If found combining the tokens that are involved with the quotes. Then inserting them back into tokens vector, rearranging the order of the vector to comply with the less tokens and deleting the junk off the back.

Comment: `tmp = tokens[i].c_str();`  Why are you calling c_str() when tokens[i] is a std::string and tmp is a std::string?

Comment: I don't think this seg-fault is the real problem. The real problem from what i see is you have single quotes then the content *between* those quotes all as separate tokens. it would appear to be your DFA (you *do* have a DFA for this, right?) isn't setup to treat a single-quote as the beginning of a const-value token. I.e. `type data = '1 2 3'` should only generate *four* tokens at read-time; not eight.

Comment: @user3339703 - Given your explanation, where are the obvious calls to std::string::find()? or any of the other std::string search functions such as find_first_of()?  And once you find the fencepost quote symbols, where is the call to substr() to get the string from between the quotes?  Your loop is overly complex, and a good portion of that complexity is caused by not using the myriad of std::string functions you could use to search and extract text.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is there no need to convert to c string when grabbing the string from the vector token into an individual string?

Comment: @user3339703 - No.  Each item in the vector is a std::string.  If it were a vector of ints, would you expect to call an "int" function to assign the value to another int?

Comment: @user3339703 - Also, given your explanation, a much safer and sounder approach would be 1) Get the text from the quotes and assign them to a temporary vector in a loop (push_back() into this temp vector).  2) When loop is done, outside of this loop, sort the data in the temporary vector using std::sort.  3) Assign this temporary token vector back to the original token vector.  With this approach, each step is easily understood, relatively easy to code, and no shenanigans of changing sizes of your input vectors while looping.

Comment: @WhozCraig I thought I was combining the tokens inside the quote by adding them to one single string. Also, I don't know if I got this across, but I want it to act like lets take an example of C'Program 5' this should all be taken as one token no just inside single quotes as one token.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wouldn't that way assign everything inside the single quotes as one token, but not take into consideration if there is a something out side the single quotes not seperated by space i.e. a'bcde f' would be two tokens not one.

Comment: @user3339703 - I think you need to do the following (on paper).  Take one of your strings, and create what another vector would look like if you tokenized the string using your criteria.  Each element in the new vector is one "token".   Now, write the code to create this new vector.  Whatever that code is, you would have eliminated the need to resize your original vector.  Then you take that new vector and do whatever else you need to do (sort, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your for loop for k.  You want to copy characters from tmp, between (and including) quotes, but you stopped referencing tmp, and went back to tokens.